# Javascript : why i have to click 2 times to run the function?

Tags: javascript

```
window.onload = function(){
   var about2 = document.getElementById("about");
   about2.addEventListener("click",about);

}

function about(){
var divabout = document.getElementById("aboutme");
 if(divabout.style.display == "none"){
    divabout.style.display = "flex";
    divabout.style.justifyContent ="center";
 }else{
    divabout.style.display ="none"; 
 }
}
```

please tell me the reason why i have to click twice to run this function .And how to fix pls . many thanks . 
i just set display:none for  1 div tag in css , and i want to change display attributes .

Comment: Please all ***all*** related code (HTML and CSS) so that we can replicate your issue.

Comment: The element style object will only contain properties set directly in the HTML markup via `style` attributes; styles affected by CSS rules will not be present. Adding and removing a `class` element is generally a much better way of doing things.

Comment: @Pointy and What does it related that i need to click twice to run the function? pls explain for me bro , i still dont understand :(

Comment: `divabout.style.display == "none"` will only be `true` if there is a "style" attribute in the HTML that sets the "display" property.

Answer (score 1):

Because you haven't set any dislplay property to your HTML by default.
That's why On first click javascript sets everything it needs. then started working from 2nd click.

Here is your code, where you dind't add style in html

```
    <div id="about">Hello</div>
    <div id="aboutme">About Me</div>
```

And Here if I fix/add this **style="display:flex;justify-content: center;"** in your about me like this

```
    <div id="about">Hello</div>
    <div id="aboutme" style="display:flex;justify-content: center;">About Me</div>
```

Now you can check you need only one click to run

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var about2 = document.getElementById("about");
  about2.addEventListener("click", about);

}

function about() {
  var divabout = document.getElementById("aboutme");
  if (divabout.style.display == "none") {
    divabout.style.display = "flex";
    divabout.style.justifyContent = "center";

  } else {
    divabout.style.display = "none";

  }
}
```

```html
<div id="about">Hello</div>
<div id="aboutme" style="display:flex;justify-content: center;">OK About Me</div>
```